# vs2010 restore default color scheme of the editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Just like in title, how can I restore default editor color scheme?
In tools there is import export settings and reset. But when I choose reset all my other settings (not only color scheme) are reset which is not what I want.

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to Tools
2. Choose Import and Export settings
3. Choose Reset All Settings
4. Choose whether to save your current settings
5. Choose which collection of settings (for example: Visual C# Development Settings) you want to reset
6. Click Finish

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reset all your settings just download the **[default theme](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/default-2)** from https://studiostyl.es/

[image: default theme]